# Lost colorscheme after recovering swap file

Tags: vim, colors, swap

I've searched for some time now and nobody seems to have the problem I do. I've got vim set up to use the colorscheme I like and it was all working perfectly until I opened a file that had a swap. I got the usual message asking if I wanted to delete it, read only or recover it. I selected recover and after doing so I've been unable to get that one file to display the colors I want.

I've tried the usual syntax:on, reloaded .vimrc and just about every normal step required to get the highlights. The strange thing is that the problem is only present for this one file when it's in the directory I recovered the swap from. Any other file I open has the colors working as usual, and if I rename the troublesome file or put it in another directory it loads the colors fine.

I figure vim must be storing its path somewhere but I have no idea where. I tried deleting .viminfo but that did nothing. Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the extension on your file? Does your swap file still exist?

Comment: The swap disappeared after I asked for it to be recovered. The extension of my file is ".hh", but I've had this happen to a ".cpp" in the past

Comment: Do you mean colorscheme or syntax highlighting? Please paste output to `:colo` and `:se ft?`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. `:colo` outputs "torte" and `se ft?` outputs "filetype="

I tried the same commands on other files and `se ft?` outputs "filetype=cpp". I'm guessing this is the problem?

Comment: UPDATE:
I correctly assumed this was the problem and searched for how to set the filetype.
`set filetype=cpp` fixed the issue. Thanks Balthamos for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sorry, I'm new to Stackoverflow. I think this is more useful as an answer to my own question than a comment:

:colo outputs "torte" and se ft? outputs "filetype=" I tried the same commands on other files and se ft? outputs "filetype=cpp". I searched for how to set the filetype and **set filetype=cpp fixed the issue**. Thanks Balthamos for pointing me in the right direction!